# Trim all whitespace in an array

Tags: vb.net

How do I trim all whitespace in an array?

```
Dim str() As String = {"Tyrannosaurus", _
       "Amarga saurus", _
       " Mamenchisaurus", _
       "Brachios aurus", _
       "Deinonychus", _
       "Tyr annosaurus", _
       " Compsognathus"}
```

Comment: Maybe you could accept some answers to your other questions... :-)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "trim"? Do you want to remove whitespace from inside the string, or just from both ends? Do you want to trim successive whitespace characters back to one, or remove them altogether?

Comment: @Matt Hamilton - it looks like "trim" means *all* whitespace. From the example, I assume the 2nd, 4th, and 6th elements should be one word each (i.e. "Amargasaurus", "Brachiosaurus", and "Tyrannosaurus" respectively).

Comment: might be a bit late to mention this but he could be referring to applying the String.trim function to each item in the array

Answer (score 3):

```
str = str.Select(Function(s) s.Replace(" ", "")).ToArray()
```

Comment: Curiosity question, but what's the cost of making a new array vs editing the current one in place? Does the compiler optimize it to the same thing?

Comment: Micro-optimization 99% of the time. Allocations in .NET are extremely fast.

Comment: I used s.trim (for the edges) and .ToList, because ILists seem more flexible than arrays to me. Thanks for this comment, even 9 years on it still helps!

Comment: wouldn't this remove all spaces from anywhere in the string and not just trim the start and ends?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim reg As New Regex("\s*")
For i = 0 To temp.Length - 1
    temp(i) = reg.Replace(temp(i), "")
Next i
```

Comment: You could also use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

I Like Jason's answer but that will remove all spaces everywhere.
if you only want to remove the starting and trailing spaces and keep the ones in the middle you need to change it slightly.

```
str = str.Select(Function(s) s.Trim).ToArray()
```

this way "Brachios aurus" is not affected because the space is inside, but " Compsognathus" will have that space in the begging removed.

it does seem like you can put in any string function in there and it'll apply it to all the items in the array